# How can I describe someone who has the 'law of the instrument' cognitive bias?

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests

The [law of the instrument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_instrument) is a cognitive bias where "if all you have is a hammer, everything looks like a nail".

What would be the best word or short phrase to describe someone who exhibits this behavior?

Comment: One is tempted to call that person "hammer-headed".

Answer (score 1):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunnel_vision_(metaphor)

According to wikipedia, if someone as metaphorical tunnel vision, it means they are reluctant "to consider alternatives to one's preferred line of thought", which fits, in that one's preferred line of thought would be analogous to the instrument in the law of the instrument